# Android Unit test API calls with Retrofit2

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, retrofit2

I haven't done any testing in Android, so please bear with me if this seems a stupid question.
I'm developing an app which makes a lot of network calls from a restful API service. To make the network calls, I'm using `Retrofit2` and `RxJava`.

What would be the best practice/framework to just test if these calls are working? I've started to read the Google Codelab for [testing](https://codelabs.developers.google.com) which uses `Junit4` and `Mockito`, but I don't want to do any clicking in the UI to start a test currently, just checking for different API versions which calls are supported or not.

Comment: I have tried it with "Junit4" but faced too many issues specially one with "App Context" while using my Rest Adapter, as our test cases are completely independent to our app. I tried with "MockContext" as well but didn't work for me.Well it's a very good question and my also looking forward for it's answers. Kindly do post your research as well.

Comment: You can use JUnit4 along with MockWebServer https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

Answer (score 4):

Here some steps for you that I am using:

- Use mockito & junit4, for sure :)
- I avoid UI tests for these cases
- Pass your retrofit Api as a parameter to a class that you want to test
- In the test create a mock retrofit api, pass this one as a parameter so you can choose what you want your "Api" to return e.g. objects or errors (see `Mockito.when()`)
- Use RxJava's `TestSubscriber` to test a method e.g. `Observable<Location> getLocationFromApi()`
- Avoid threading in your testing class (e.g. like `.observeOn(mainThread())`). If inevitable use `awaitTerminalEvents` in TestSubscriber. If there is no terminal even rethink your test

General tips:

- Try to modularize your code so each class has few functionality -> easier to test.
- Be patient and don't expect to write tests for e.g. 5% of your code in just one week :) It's a slow process regardless team size

Comment: Thank you for your detailed steps, I will try this out :)